# SonarQube: How to configure Components List View for a specific Project?

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarQube portal, it is possible to customize the columns for the Components List view. However, doing this affects all projects and views.

[image]

Is there a way to customize only a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Note that you might be able to get what you're after with a saved Measures filter with the correct column set displayed in the Measure Filter as List widget on a dashboard. If you make that dashboard public, then it will show up the same for all projects, but you will have gotten the columns you want while leaving the Components view alone.

Comment: ok, but this means that users would need to go to that custom Measure Filter, instead of using the "Components" tab. is it?

Comment: Yes, to that filter or to the dashboard you put it on.